# Handling single level routes in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on a small SPA with asp.net core + angular2.

Naturally, I would like all my routes to return Home/Index page, which hosts the app.

Howeever, I am having some trouble with this.

In my startUp.cs file

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                     "default",                                               // Route name 
                    "{*any}",                                           // URL with parameters (matching anything)
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults to Error/404
                );
        });
```

I am using this code.

But the issue I am having
if the url is http://localhost:43515/ - everything works fine
http://localhost:43515/NonExistingController/NonExistingAction - works fine
http://localhost:43515/singleLevelRoute - {"id":["The value 'singleLevelRoute' is not valid for Int32."]}

What is the cause for this?
I am very puzzled.

Please advise.

Comment: do you have any routing overrides in your controllers?

Comment: I have a couple of RouteAttributes on api controllers.
such as 
[Route("Api/Stuff")].

Comment: Somewhere you have a route looking for {id:int}. Can you search your project for this string?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the belated reply.
you were correct and thank you.

This string was a result of scaffolding